# How to find how many solutions of a second order ODE satisfy given initial conditions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am trying to find how many solutions of a second order ODE satisfy given initial conditions. For example how many solutions of $3xy'' + y' = 0$ satisfy $y(1)=y'(1)=1$, $y''(1)=-3$?

Is there an existence and uniqueness theorem I can apply for second order equations to show there is one solution? Or shall I solve the equation and see how many solutions I end up with?

Comment: the constant function is one solution and for the other make the ansatz $$y=x^r$$

Comment: In your example, if you want $y'' = -3$ and $y' = 1$ at $x = 1$, you have $3 x y'' + y' = 3 (1) (-3) + (1) = -8 \neq 0$.  So for this specific case, there are no solutions.  In general, if your initial conditions involve the second derivative, you can often rule out existence of solutions simply by examining the ODE itself.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelSeifert , if I had substituted in these initial conditions and had got it equaling 0 and not -8, would that mean that only one solution exists?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that for a single first-order equation, we have the [standard existence and uniqueness theorem:](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~troby/Math200S08/existence.pdf)  if we have
$$
u' = F(x, u), \qquad u(a) = b, 
$$
where $F$ and $\partial F/\partial u$ are continuous at $(a,b)$, then there exists a finite-sized interval centered at $a$ on which a unique solution to this ODE exists.  This theorem can also be extended to coupled systems of ODEs:
$$
u_i' = F_i(x, u_j), \qquad u_i(a) = b_i, 
$$
where $i$ & $j$ run over the number of functions we're trying to solve for, and we have extended the derivative conditions on the functions $F_i$ in the obvious way.

Second, note that any $n$th-order equation can be put into first-order form:  if we have the equations and initial conditions
$$
y^{(n)} = F(x, y, y', ... y^{(n-1)}), \quad y(a) = b_1, y'(a) = b_2, \dots, y^{(n-1)} = b_{n},
$$
then we can define $u_i = y^{(i-1)}$, and the system becomes
\begin{align*}
u_1' &= u_2 & u_1(a) &= b_1 \\
u_2' &= u_3 & u_2(a) &= b_2 \\
&\vdots && \vdots& \\
u'_{n-1} &= u_n & u_{n-1}(a) &= b_{n-1} \\
u'_n &= F(x, u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n) & u_n(a) &= b_n
\end{align*}
which is in the first-order form from above.  Thus, a unique solution to this system (and therefore to our original ODE) exists in some interval centered about $a$.

Finally, note that the interval of validity can be found explicitly for a linear ODE of any order in the same way;  in this case we have
$$
u_i' + \sum_j f_{ij}(x) u_j = g_i(x)
$$ 
and the interval of validity of our solution will be the largest interval that contains $a$ and does not contain any singularities of the functions $f_{ij}(x)$ or $g_i(x)$.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelSeifert, this makes a lot more sense now!